# JettyHttpContainerFactory and ServletContextHandler

Tags: jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to use embedded Jetty and Jersey. After some tests I ended up using `JettyHttpContainerFactory`, but I realise, that with this container
factory I can not configure `ServletContextHandler`, because Server which is
generated already uses `JettyHttpContainer`.

Is there some way, how I can add `ServletContextHandler` using `JettyHttpContainerFactory`? 
Here is my code:

```
    URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(8080).build();
    // This is what I want in addition
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    EnvironmentLoaderListener listener = new EnvironmentLoaderListener();
    context.callContextInitialized(listener, new ServletContextEvent(new ContextHandler.NoContext()));
    context.addEventListener(listener);
    DatabaseContextListener databaseListener = new DatabaseContextListener();
    context.addEventListener(databaseListener);
    context.setAttribute(DatabaseContextListener.DB_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTE, databaseListener);

    FilterHolder filterHolder = new FilterHolder();
    filterHolder.setFilter(new ShiroFilter());
    EnumSet<DispatcherType> types = EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class);
    context.addFilter(filterHolder, "/*", types);
    ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
    holder.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "org.vrabec.datagateway.rest");

    context.addServlet(holder, "/*");

    // This part is working as expected
    ResourceConfig configuration = new ResourceConfig().packages("org.vrabec.datagateway.rest").register(GensonCustomResolver.class);
    Server server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, configuration, false);

    // This is what I want in addition
    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
    server.join();
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Firstly please post all relevant code so we can see what you have done so far. it makes it much easier to answer your question. Secondly please ask fewer questions, preferably one. this makes it much more likely that you will get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I managed how to do it. This is source code:

```java
    Server server = new Server(PORT_NUMBER);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");

    EnvironmentLoaderListener listener = new EnvironmentLoaderListener();
    context.callContextInitialized(listener, new ServletContextEvent(new ContextHandler.NoContext())); 
    context.addEventListener(listener);
    DatabaseContextListener databaseListener = new DatabaseContextListener();
    context.addEventListener(databaseListener);
    context.setAttribute(DatabaseContextListener.DB_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTE, databaseListener);

    FilterHolder filterHolder = new FilterHolder(); 
    filterHolder.setFilter(new ShiroFilter()); 
    EnumSet<DispatcherType> types = EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class); 
    context.addFilter(filterHolder, "/*", types); 

    ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(new ResourceConfig()
    .packages("org.vrabec.datagateway.rest")
    .register(GensonCustomResolver.class)));    
    holder.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "org.vrabec.datagateway.rest");

    context.addServlet(holder, "/*");
    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
    server.join();
```